# Mosquitto broker: How to refuse particular topic?

Tags: mosquitto

The application has many clients. They use same "User name" and random "Client ID" to connect brocker. They may sub/pub any `TOPIC`.
Now I want to refuse some particular `TOPIC`.
How should I configure the broker?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Mosquitto ACLs can use `pattern` entries which use the `%c` substitution marker which includes the client id in the topic.

This means you can control access to a topic based on the client id.

From the mosquitto.conf man [page](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html):

> It is also possible to define ACLs based on pattern substitution
>   within the topic. The form is the same as for the topic keyword, but
>   using pattern as the keyword.
>
> **pattern [read|write|readwrite]**
>
> The patterns available for substition are:
>
> %c to match the client id of the client %u to match the username of
>   the client The substitution pattern must be the only text for that
>   level of hierarchy. Pattern ACLs apply to all users even if the "user"
>   keyword has previously been given.
>
> Example:
>
> **pattern write sensor/%u/data**
>
> Allow access for bridge connection messages:
>
> **pattern write $SYS/broker/connection/%c/state**

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you can use ACL.

There are examples how to target a specific user:
https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/aclfile.example

You could deny a topic for everyone, and allow only certain trusted users.

More info:
https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html#idm44